# Let A be a closed discrete set inside a compact set K. Show that A is finite.

Tags: complex-analysis, discrete-mathematics, metric-spaces, compactness

Clearly, A must be compact also, so I'm assuming this proof requires the use of all 3 factors - closed, discrete & compact - but I'm not quite sure how to actually use these in a proper proof. 
Any help/hints/explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try proving "A discrete compact space is finite".

Comment: @DanielFischer Do you need closed? See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know (or can prove) that a [closed subset of a compact set is compact](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Closed_Subspace_of_Compact_Space_is_Compact).  Therefore, $A$ is compact.  We are also given that $A$ is discrete, which means that, for each $x \in A$, we can find a neighborhood $N_x$ of $x$ such that $N_x \cap A = \{x\}$.

Notice that $\{N_x \}_{x \in X}$ is an open cover of $A$...

Comment: ahhhh yea I see! thank you

Comment: KajHansen Do you need closed? See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is infinite, then $A$ has a limit point because $K$ is limit point compact. I did not make use of $A$ being closed.